# Purpose of 'ax' keyword in pandas scatter_matrix function

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, pandas, scatter-plot

I'm puzzled by the meaning of the '**ax**' keyword in the pandas **scatter_matrix** function:

pd.scatter_matrix(frame, alpha=0.5, figsize=None, **ax=None**, grid=False, diagonal='hist', marker='.', density_kwds={}, hist_kwds={}, **kwds)

The only clue given in the docstring for the ax keyword is too cryptic for me:

```
ax : Matplotlib axis object
```

I had a look in the pandas code for the scatter_matrix function, and the ax variable is incorporated in the following matplotlib subplots call:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=n, ncols=n, figsize=figsize, ax=ax,
                         squeeze=False)
```

But, for the life of me, I can't find any reference to an 'ax' keyword in matplotlib subplots!

Can anyone tell me what this ax keyword is for???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, it targets a subplot within a grid.

If you have `nrows=2` and `ncols=2`, for example, then `ax` allows you to plot on a specific axis by passing `ax=axes[0,0]` (top left) or `ax=axes[1,1]` (bottom right), etc.

When you create the subplots, you receive an `axes` variable. You can later plot (or subplot) with an element of that `axes` variable as above.

Take a look at the **"Targeting different subplots"** section of this page: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/visualization.html#targeting-different-subplots

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

This is tricky here. When looking at the source of pandas `scatter_matrix` you will find this line right after the docstring:

```
fig, axes = _subplots(nrows=n, ncols=n, figsize=figsize, ax=ax, squeeze=False)
```

Hence, internally, a new figure, axes combination is created using the internal `_subplots` method. This is strongly related to the matplotlibs `subplots` command but slightly different. Here, the `ax` keyword is supplied as well. If you look at the corresponding source (`pandas.tools.plotting._subplots`) you will find these lines:

```
if ax is None:
    fig = plt.figure(**fig_kw)
else:
    fig = ax.get_figure()
    fig.clear()
```

Hence, if you supply an axes object (e.g. created using matplotlibs `subplots` command), pandas `scatter_matrix` grabs the corresponding (matplolib) figure object and deletes its content. Afterwards a new subplots grid is created into this figure object.

All in all, the `ax` keyword allows to plot the scatter matrix into a *given* figure (even though IMHO in a slightly strange way).