# How to create subplots with Pandas Scatter Matrix

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

So I'm trying to create a subplot of pandas scatter matrices but have run into a bit of a wall. I've looked around at other similar questions, but none of the answers seemed to fix it. Right now I'm just trying to create a subplot of 2 of them. I'm going to move to a two by two subplot at some point, but am just trying to start small just to get it working. Here is my code

```
df_SH = pd.DataFrame({'East_Pacific_SH':DJF_con_SH_east_finite_all, 
                   'West_Pacific_SH':DJF_con_SH_west_finite_all,
                   'Atl_SH':DJF_con_SH_atl_finite_all,
                  'Zonal_SH':DJF_con_SH_zonal_finite_all})

df_NH = pd.DataFrame({'East_Pacific_NH':DJF_con_NH_east_finite_all, 
                   'West_Pacific_NH':DJF_con_NH_west_finite_all,
                   'Atl_NH':DJF_con_NH_atl_finite_all,
                  'Zonal_NH':DJF_con_NH_zonal_finite_all})

region_name=np.array(['East_Pacific_SH', 'West_Pacific_SH', 'Atl_SH', 'Zonal_SH'])


plt.suptitle('Control Correlations')
plt.subplot(211)
axes = pd.scatter_matrix(df_SH, alpha=0.2, diagonal='kde')
corr = df_SH.corr().as_matrix()
for i, j in zip(*plt.np.triu_indices_from(axes, k=1)):
    axes[j, i].annotate("%.3f" %corr[j,i], (.8, .9), xycoords='axes fraction', ha='center', va='center')
plt.title('Control DJF SH', size = 15)
#plt.savefig(filename='DJF_SH_Control_Scatter.pdf', ftype='pdf')
#plt.show()

plt.subplot(212)
axes2 = pd.scatter_matrix(df_NH, alpha=0.2, diagonal='kde')
corr2 = df_NH.corr().as_matrix()
for i, j in zip(*plt.np.triu_indices_from(axes, k=1)):
    axes2[j, i].annotate("%.3f" %corr2[j,i], (.8, .9), xycoords='axes fraction', ha='center', va='center')
plt.title('Control DJF NH', size = 15)
#plt.savefig(filename='DJF_NH_Control_Scatter.pdf', ftype='pdf')
plt.show()
```

Here are the results

[image: result]

[image: result]

[image: result]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I'm trying to create a a subplot of two pandas scatter matrices as I said. With my code my result yields a blank box, the bottom half one matrix, and a full matrix with the title for some reason only over one cell instead of the whole matrix. I want both of the scatter matrices correctly subplotted next to each other

Comment: I am afraid what you want is not possible using off the shelf functions. You are currently not providing pd.scatter_matrix() with an axis to plot into. Therefore, it by default creates a new figure and generates a matrix of subplots. You can specify an axis but somewhat strangely, that will erase the ENTIRE figure belonging to that axis. Also see this explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20853179/purpose-of-ax-keyword-in-pandas-scatter-matrix-function Your second plt.subplot() command effectively erases the bottom of your first scatter matrix. hope this looking for alternatives...

Answer (score 2):

`pandas` doesn't currently do that, although it has a promising `ax` argument:

```
iris = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('iris.csv')
chicks = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('ChickWeight.csv')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2)

#iris.plot.scatter('PL', 'PW', ax = axs[0])        
#chicks.plot.scatter('Diet', 'Chick', ax = axs[1]) # This is fine.

pd.scatter_matrix(iris, ax=axs[0], alpha=0.2)
pd.scatter_matrix(chicks, ax=axs[1], alpha=0.2)    # This clears axes unexpectedly.

plt.savefig('two_pd_scatter.png')
```

gives warning

> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py:3303: UserWarning: To output multiple subplots, the figure containing the passed axes is being cleared
>
> "is being cleared", UserWarning)

Note that it's specifically clearing the whole *figure*, not just the passed axes.

I'd fix this by generating four tight-margin, systematically named figures for the scatter matrices and set up a document (TeX, whatever) that imports those figures in the right places and with the right title.